# Switching viewModels with flatMap swift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a viewModel where I am performing a check based on bool. True / False. This value is passed into a `PublishSubject<Bool>()` now I want to get the latestValue with flatMapLatest and navigate using another different ViewModel based on the value of True/False

```
routeManager.errorOnNil().asObservable()

            .flatMapLatest { (code) -> Observable<RxSwift.Event<User>> in
            let params = code.values
                let challengeId = Int(params["challengeId"] as? String ?? "0")

            return self.provider.postVerifyApp(challengeId: login.challengeId!)
            .trackActivity(self.loading)
            .trackError(self.error)
            .materialize()
        }.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (event) in
            switch event {
            case .next(let token):
                log(token)
                if token.data != nil {
                    self?.dataStatus.onNext(true)
                } else {
                    self?.dataStatus.onNext(false)
                }
            case .error(let error):
                log(error.localizedDescription)
            default: break
            }
        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
```

Where to switch

```
dataStatus.flatMapLatest { (status) -> ViewModel in
            if status {
                let viewModel = XXXViewModel(provider: self.provider)
                return viewModel
            } else {
                let viewModel = YYYYViewModel(provider: self.provider)
                return viewModel
            }
        }.subscribe()
            .disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
```

this gives error `Instance method 'flatMapLatest' requires that 'ViewModel' conform to 'ObservableConvertibleType'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.flatMapLatest` and `.flatMap` take `Observable` types as return values for their closures.  You need to return the `viewModel` wrapped inside an observable.  `.flatMapLatest` will flatten that down and when you subscribe you'll get the `viewModel` object.

```swift
dataStatus.flatMapLatest { (status) -> Observable<ViewModel> in
            if status {
                let viewModel = XXXViewModel(provider: self.provider)
                return Observable.just(viewModel)
            } else {
                let viewModel = YYYYViewModel(provider: self.provider)
                return Observable.just(viewModel)
            }
        }.subscribe()
        .disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
```